# AWS S3 - Website-Redirect-Location header ignoring all other metadata?

Tags: redirect, amazon-s3

I have a bucket on S3 that is configured to be a static website. I'd like to have any requests to the root domain automatically redirect to a subfolder, for instance `example.com => example.com/campaign`.

This can be accomplished by applying the `Website-Redirect-Location` metadata to the root `index.html` object. However when I apply this all other metadata values I add appear to be getting ignored. Is this the intended behavior? Can I not apply other metadata if I'm doing a redirect?

In my particular use-case, I'd like to be able to apply `Cache-Control` and `Expires` headers on my `index.html` object so I can change the redirect value (for instance, change the redirect to `example.com => example.com/new-campaign`) and have browsers invalidate their cache. Is there any way to accomplish this with S3?